# deploy Golang app (api) with config.toml file

Tags: go

I have created a small golang API (nrfapi) which include a config.toml file. I would like to deploy the api on other ubuntu VM therefore i build the API using the "GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build" and then scp the build file to the VM /var/www/go diretory. I also create a unit file (nrf.service) ending in .service within the /etc/systemd/system directory. In the .service file i have the following configuration

```
[Unit]
Description= instance to serve nrf api
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data

ExecStart=/var/www/go/nrfapi)

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ERROR

```
Error

● nrf.service - instance to serve nrf api
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nrf.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-03-30 16:44:51 EET; 11s ago
 Main PID: 4066 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 30 16:44:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started instance to serve nrf api.
Mar 30 16:44:51 ubuntu nrfapi[4066]: 2019/03/30 16:44:51 open config.toml: no such file or directory
Mar 30 16:44:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: nrf.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 16:44:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: nrf.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 30 16:44:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: nrf.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

However, after starting the API using the following commands

sudo systemctl start nrfapi
sudo systemctl enable nrfapi

the API is not running. I realize from the error message above that the API need the config.toml file configurations.

My problem now is that i dont know which directory to place the config.toml file so that the golang api can read the configuration parameters from there. Can anyone help me solve this? How do i go about this?

Comment: Have you tried to change the `WorkingDirectory` of the server?

Comment: Hi, yes I did and it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use relative paths to files in your Go scrips then executable will look for them relative to the current working directory. To change working directory in `systemd` just add `WorkingDirectory` parameter to the `Service` section:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/go
```

And place `config.toml` file inside `/var/www/go` dir.

You can also embed static files into Go binary using this library: https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr